# JQGrid: making all checkboxes checked by default

Tags: jqgrid, default, checkbox, checked

After adding following in JQGrid :-

### Models

```
{name: 'checkbox', index: 'checkbox', width:"5%", formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
```

### Columns

"Select"

JQGrid has displayed column having check boxes that is correct but by default all check boxes are checked that is not expected.

I am not sure if this is the default behavior of JQGrid check box column. I don't want to display all check boxes checked by default. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Per default checkboxes are **non-checked**. You can use `defaultValue` property of `formatoptions` to change default value:

```js
formatoptions: {defaultValue: "yes"}
```

By the way the setting of `width` in % (like `width:"5%"`) is not supported by jqGrid.

Comment: do that mean after adding formatoptions: {defaultValue: "yes"}, "yes" will become default value for all check boxes? and also those all check boxes will not be checked while landing over page? My intention is to simple keep check boxes with their relevant id as a value for those check boxes and by default they should un-checked.

Comment: @neeraj: The first problem is that I can't reproduce the problem which you described. If the value for the column having `formatter: "checkbox"` is not defined it will be displayed as **not checked**. You should include more full code of jqGrid which you use and include example of input data for the grid. Moreover you can try to use `formatoptions: {defaultValue: "no"}` if you redefined the standard default behavior of `formatter: "checkbox"`.

Comment: @neeraj: I don't understand what you mean about ids in your last commend: ("My intention is to simple keep check boxes with their relevant id as a value..."). Could you explain want you need in other words or better on an example.

Comment: I got another way "multiselect: true" to have a column containing check boxes with their relevant ids and that has solved my problem. As long as using {name: 'checkbox', index: 'checkbox', width:"5%", formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false } }, is concerned, i think i should leave this as of now. But i appreciate your help.

Comment: i am sorry for making such confusion. By ids mean the primary key (id fields of that model) for those check boxes.

Comment: @neeraj: jqGrid assign `id` attribute to *rows* of the grid (to `<tr>` elements) and not to cells of some column (`<td>` elements of the column 'checkbox' for example). `multiselect: true` is absolutely another thing. It means very special behavior of selection of *rows* together with setting of checkboxes. Moreover your main question about **default value** of `formatter: "checkbox"` still incorrect. Look at the checkboxes of "test2" and "test3" of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DefaultValueOfEnabledCheckbox.htm). Defaults as **unchecked** in the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem:

{ **name: "id"**, **index: 'id'**, width: '110', hidden: true},

{ **name: 'id'**, width: "100", **index: 'id'**, key: true, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No'} formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false } },

I had same problem i resolved it... Here is the Solution...
you must be  using same name & index for two columns .
Corrected Code:

{ **name: "id"**, **index: 'id'**, width: '110', hidden: true},

{ **name: 'checkbox'**, width: "100", **index: 'checkbox'**, key: true, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No'} formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false } },